# Is there a better way to design these classes?

Tags: php, object-oriented, dependency-injection

I have two business classes: TimesheetDay and TimeSlot. One TimesheetDay can have one or more TimeSlots.

The TimesheetDay and TimeSlot classes will be dependent on an object that implements a corresponding TimesheetDayData and TimeSlotData interface. That way, I can write data classes to map the objects to a MySQL database, but if I use another way to store the data in the future, I can inject objects from a different dataclass.

These objects will not create other objects, and I refuse to use the "new" keyword in them. I want them to be testable in complete isolation.

For example, I instantiate a TimesheetDay object like this (in a container):

```
$mTimesheetDayData = new TimesheetDayMysqlData($databaseHost, $timesheetDayId);
$mTimesheetDay = new TimesheetDay($mTimesheetDayData);
```

TimeSlot objects will be constructed the same way:

```
$mTimeSlotData = new TimeSlotMySqlData($databaseHost, $timeSlotId);
$mTimeSlot = new TimeSlot($mTimeSlotData);
```

My problem lies in getting TimeSlot objects that the TimesheetDay contains. I can't have the TimesheetDay class creating objects. Otherwise, I might write a method that returns an array of TimeSlot objects, something like:

```
$timeSlotsForThatDay = array();
$timeSlotsForThatDay = $mTimesheetDay->getTimeSlots();
```

But, that would require the method getTimeSlots() to create objects.

How would you handle this?

Comment: `$timeSlotsForThatDay = array();` Why would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to create one more class - `TimesheetDataMapper`, it would map mysql data and objects. As I understand, you intend to make `TimesheetDay` and `TimeSlot` as POPO (Plain Old Php Object). That is a good intention :)

So what you have to do is inject `TimeSlotMySqlData` into `TimesheetDataMapper`, there have a method `getTimesheetDay($someCriteriaOrId);` which would get the data from mysql based on criteria, create new object `TimesheetDay`, select time slot data & inject it into `TimesheetDay`.

```
class TimesheetDataMapper {
    protected function _getTimeSlotData($someCriteriaOrId)
    {
         $timeSlotsForReturn = array();

         $someTimeSlotListFromDb; 
         foreach ($someTimeSlotListFromDb as $timeSlotData) {
             $timeSlotsForReturn[] = new TimeSlot($timeSlotData);
         } 

         return $timeSlotsForReturn;
    }
    public function getTimesheetDay($someCriteriaOrId) 
    {
        $timeSlotData = $this->_getTimeSlotData($someCriteriaOrId);
        $timesheetDay = new TimesheetDay($timeSlotData);

        return $timesheetDay;
    }
}
```

You could also have some setters/getters on `TimesheetDay` / `TimeSlot`.

Answer (score 0):

The TimesheetDay object should query the database for data to construct its list of TimeSlots, either when it is constructed, or [the first time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) getTimeSlots is called.